# Difference Between NearestNeighbors and KNN Classifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I just wondering what is the difference between NearestNeighbors from sklearn.neighbors and KNN Classifier from sklearn.neighbors ?

Answer (score 3):

I can try giving some illustrative insights into each of these methods.

`NearestNeighbors` is an unsupervised technique of finding the nearest data points with respect to each data point, we only fit X in here.

`KNN Classifier` is a supervised technique of finding the cluster a point belongs to by fitting X and Y and then using the predict().

Let's take an example from the documentation itself:

1. **`NearestNeigbors`**

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=3, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(X) #neighbors = 3
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(X)
```

The code above creates six different points and tries to find the distances and indices wrt to each point. Let's see first of all how the points look like in 2D

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1])
```

[image]

As we can see the point0 is closest to point1, and point1 is closest to point0, point2 is closest to point1, and so on. .

Let's see what indices give us: The same result!
Note: We have 3 columns as we chose neighbors = 3

```
>>> indices
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 3, 5],
       [5, 4, 3]])
```

You can even find the distances amongst each points by running `distances`, I'll leave that for you to try. Also, scikit-learn provides us with sparse matrix representation, which we can see down below with neighbors = 3.

```
>>> nbrs.kneighbors_graph(X).toarray()
array([[1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Going back to classical KNN

2. **`KNN Classifier`**

```
>>> X = [[0], [1], [2], [3]] 
    y = [0, 0, 1, 1]
    from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
    neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
    neigh.fit(X, y)
KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
```

Lets look at the plot of points X and y
`plt.scatter(X,y)`

[image]

Applying the predict() for the point 1.1, and it gives us the predicted cluster. I don't feel it needs to be explained any further.

```
>>> print(neigh.predict([[1.1]]))
[0]
```